# Select with Multiple Conditions in Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm probably over thinking this, but here's the scenario... I have a function to increase the Update # by one while retaining the same Booking # when one of the Descriptive Fields is modified and the modified booking is saved to a new Control # in Table 1.

Table 1

```
Control # | Booking # | Bunch of Descriptive Fields | Update # |
----------|-----------|-----------------------------|----------|
    1     |     1     |         ........            |     0    |
    2     |     2     |         ........            |     0    |
    3     |     3     |         ........            |     0    |
    4     |     1     |         ........            |     1    |
    5     |     4     |         ........            |     0    |
    6     |     2     |         ........            |     1    |
    7     |     1     |         ........            |     2    |
```

The goal is to have an ObservableCollection filled with a filtered table where rows are selected on Distinct values from Booking # field using the highest Update # for each respective Booking #. I have tried most all SELECT solutions to create the table from the net including UNION, JOIN, multiple SELECT statements, etc. and nothing has worked properly. What I would like is a resulting table like this:

```
Control # | Booking # | Bunch of Descriptive Fields | Update # |
----------|-----------|-----------------------------|----------|
    7     |     1     |         ........            |     2    |
    6     |     2     |         ........            |     1    |
    3     |     3     |         ........            |     0    |
    5     |     4     |         ........            |     0    |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.update = (select max(t2.update) from t t2 where t2.booking = t.booking);
```

This solution can have very good performance with an index on `(booking, update)` (both columns, in that order).